# Blackberry console

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Where can I find the printable statements in BlackBerry Eclipse IDE. The console which I see does not gives me the string which I print

```
System.out.println("User1 "+Username);
```

It just shows:

```
Packaging project HelloWorld
C:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.1.0_7.1.0.10\components\bin\rapc.exe -convertpng -quiet codename=deliverables\Standard\7.1.0\HelloWorld -sourceroot=C:\Users\Ravi\workspace\HelloWorld\src;C:\Users\Ravi\workspace\HelloWorld\res -import=C:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.1.0_7.1.0.10\components\lib\net_rim_api.jar deliverables\Standard\7.1.0\HelloWorld.rapc C:\Users\Ravi\workspace\HelloWorld\bin
Packaging project HelloWorld succeeded (took 1.63 seconds)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute some print statements like

```
System.out.println("Test")
```

to track your application status, you should debug your application to get your print statements.  It will not print the statements if you run your application normally.

Do **Right Click** your application, and click **Debug as yourapplication**, and then you will be able to get print statements

Comment: Actually i went for debugging i have a problem in that iam gettting Source not found.